# Javascript: How should I handle token verification on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, security, token

Let's say that in my web app that I have a token that I received from some token server stored in localStorage. Then, the user refreshes. Now I have a token that may or may not be valid since I don't know how long it's been since I received the token.

Should I check the validity of the token instantly upon refreshing before using it? Or should I just assume the token is valid and use it in requests, throwing an error otherwise? Or is there a third better option that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you give this token everytime you make a call to the server to retrieve datas, templates,...

So I think your 2nd option (Assume the token is valid and use it in requests, throwing an error otherwise) is the best, and can be shared in all your web application (you may not know where the user will try to refresh is browser).
You will try to parse it and check the validity. If one of the steps failed, you can throw an error.

With the 1st option, you also need to know on client side how the token was hashed by the server. I don't recommend you this option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Regarding the first option, I think the API I'm using has a way to send a token and check to see whether or not the token is valid. Would that make option 1 more viable?

Comment: Yes with this approach. In fine the validation of the token will be made on server side (by the API you're using)